# Creating Foldout menu with uGUI

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does anyone know how to do a foldout menu with the new GUI system? With NGUI I would have anchored a panel of content the the bottom of the button, tweening the scale of the panel when the button was clicked, and anchored the next button to the previous panel (and so on).

Due to the RectTransform anchors only working based on the parent, my method isn't really possible. Has anyone else come across a solution for such a problem?

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/a-working-stylable-combo-box-drop-down-list.264167/

Comment: A combo box is not the same as what I'm looking for here. Rather than a single dropdown, I have multiple buttons each hiding a panel of other UI. When one opens, it's panel needs to animate and all the other buttons need to move down to give it space. Like this - http://paxcel.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Screen-Shot-2012-08-01-at-4.11.11-PM1.png